# illegal start of expression in public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

i'm making a simple game in java. but i'm getting errors "illegal start of expression" in  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e). help give a Solution.

```
 public class Game extends JFrame{
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    JPanel dasar = new JPanel(cl);

    public Game() {
        dasar.add(new level1(),"Level 1");
        add(dasar,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Game G = new Game();
        G.setTitle("PuzzleGame");
        G.setSize(500,500);
        G.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        G.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        G.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

card layout class

```
class level1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
public level1(){
JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,sample;
Icon star;
star = b9.getIcon();

Icon ic0 = new ImageIcon("Sample.jpg");
Icon ic1 = new ImageIcon("1.jpg");
Icon ic2 = new ImageIcon("2.jpg");
Icon ic3 = new ImageIcon("3.jpg");
Icon ic4 = new ImageIcon("4.jpg");
Icon ic5 = new ImageIcon("5.jpg");
Icon ic6 = new ImageIcon("6.jpg");
Icon ic7 = new ImageIcon("7.jpg");
Icon ic8 = new ImageIcon("8.jpg");
Icon ic9 = new ImageIcon("*.jpg");

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gb = new GridBagConstraints();

    gb.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gb.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

    gb.gridx = 0;
    gb.gridy = 0;
    gb.gridwidth = 1;
    gb.gridheight = 1;
    gb.weightx = 1;
    gb.weighty = 1;
    b1 = new JButton(ic2);
    add(b1,gb);

    gb.gridx = 1;
    b2 = new JButton(ic1);
    add(b2,gb);

    gb.gridx = 2;
    b3 = new JButton(ic4);
    add(b3,gb);

    gb.gridx = 0;
    gb.gridy = 1;
    gb.gridwidth = 1;
    gb.gridheight = 1;
    gb.weightx = 1;
    gb.weighty = 1;
    b4 = new JButton(ic3);
    add(b4,gb);

    gb.gridx = 1;
    b5 = new JButton(ic8);
    add(b5,gb);

    gb.gridx = 2;
    b6 = new JButton(ic5);
    add(b6,gb);

    gb.gridx = 0;
    gb.gridy = 2;
    gb.gridwidth = 1;
    gb.gridheight = 1;
    gb.weightx = 1;
    gb.weighty = 1;
    b7 = new JButton(ic7);

    gb.gridx = 1;
    b8 = new JButton(ic6);
    add(b8,gb);

    gb.gridx = 2;
    b9 = new JButton(ic9);
    add(b9,gb);

    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    b4.addActionListener(this);
    b5.addActionListener(this);
    b6.addActionListener(this);
    b7.addActionListener(this);
    b8.addActionListener(this);
    b9.addActionListener(this);

}
```

}

and this is a action event i put in public level1

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
{
        if (e.getSource() == b1){
            Icon s1 = b1.getIcon();
            if(b2.getIcon() == star){
                b2.setIcon(s1);
                b1.setIcon(star);
            }
            else if (b4.getIcon() == star){
                b4.setIcon(s1);
                b1.setIcon(star);
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == b2){
            Icon s1 = b2.getIcon();
            if(b1.getIcon() == star){
                b1.setIcon(s1);
                b2.setIcon(star);
            }
            else if (b5.getIcon() == star){
                b5.setIcon(s1);
                b2.setIcon(star);
            }
            else if (b3.getIcon() == star){
                b3.setIcon(s1);
                b2.setIcon(star);
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == b3){
            Icon s1 = b3.getIcon();
            if (b2.getIcon() == star){
                b2.setIcon(s1);
                b3.setIcon(star);
            }
            else if (b6.getIcon() == star){
                b6.setIcon(s1);
                b3.setIcon(star);
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == b4){
            Icon s1 = b4.getIcon();
            if (b1.getIcon() == star){
                b1.setIcon(s1);
                b4.setIcon(star);
            }
            else if (b5.getIcon() == star){
                b5.setIcon(s1);
                b4.setIcon(star);
            }
            else if (b7.getIcon() == star){
                b7.setIcon(s1);
                b4.setIcon(star);
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == b5){
            Icon s1 = b5.getIcon();
            if (b2.getIcon() == star){
                b2.setIcon(s1);
                b5.setIcon(star);
            }
            else if (b6.getIcon() == star){
                b6.setIcon(s1);
                b5.setIcon(star);
            }
            else if (b4.getIcon() == star){
                b4.setIcon(s1);
                b5.setIcon(star);
            }
            else if (b8.getIcon() == star){
                b8.setIcon(s1);
                b5.setIcon(star);
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == b6){
            Icon s1 = b6.getIcon();
            if (b3.getIcon() == star){
                b3.setIcon(s1);
                b6.setIcon(star);
            }
            else if (b5.getIcon() == star){
                b5.setIcon(s1);
                b6.setIcon(star);
            }
            else if (b9.getIcon() == star){
                b9.setIcon(s1);
                b6.setIcon(star);
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == b7){
            Icon s1 = b7.getIcon();
            if (b4.getIcon() == star){
                b4.setIcon(s1);
                b7.setIcon(star);
            }
            else if (b8.getIcon() == star){
                b8.setIcon(s1);
                b7.setIcon(star);
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == b8){
            Icon s1 = b8.getIcon();
            if(b5.getIcon() == star){
                b5.setIcon(s1);
                b8.setIcon(star);
            }
            else if (b7.getIcon() == star){
                b7.setIcon(s1);
                b8.setIcon(star);
            }
            else if (b9.getIcon() == star){
                b9.setIcon(s1);
                b8.setIcon(star);
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == b9){
            Icon s1 = b9.getIcon();
            if(b6.getIcon() == star){
                b6.setIcon(s1);
                b9.setIcon(star);
            }
            else if (b8.getIcon() == star){
                b8.setIcon(s1);
                b9.setIcon(star);
            }
        }
    }
```

please give me solution

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.  Note you can always [edit your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29574866/edit).

Comment: Hint: don't code dozens or hundreds line of code **before** running the compiler the first time. Especially when you are a beginner: start small. Meaning: first start with an empty class. Then add empty methods. Then start adding content for an method ... and so on. And after adding 5 or 10 lines of code - run the compiler. Consider using an IDE - it tells you immediately when you got the syntax wrong. Anything else simply waists   time/motivation. This requires some degree of "discipline", but it will still be much more fun to program this way (you avoid the long periods of bug searching!)

Comment: Coding hint number two: dont create 10 different objects and name them b1, b2, b3, ... Instead, you can use arrays or ArrayLists. This makes your code **much** shorter; easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

`star`, `b1`, `b2`, `b3` only exist within the scope of `level1`'s constructor. If you need them later (i.e. for comparison in an action handler), define them at class-level:

```
class level1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,sample;
    Icon star;
    [...]
    public level1(){
        this.b1 = createButton(1);
        [...]
```

In the `actionPerformed` method, you can then access them like this:

```
    if (e.getSource() == this.b1){
        [...]
```

Comment: i change it, but i'm getting errors "cannot find symbol" in create button
i put icon ic1 = ... in class level 

this.b1 = createButton(ic2);

Comment: `if (e.getSource() == level1.this.b1){` should be `if (e.getSource() == this.b1){`, because `level1` itself is the action listener - I didn't notice that earlier. I'll update my answer. Please update your question to your new code, and also state the location (which line) of the error.

Comment: FYI (this seems unclear based on your other question): `[...]` means "something follows, but is irrelevant here", and the `createButton()` was short for "insert whatever code creates that button here".